# How to append Html.Action to view by using javascript

Tags: javascript, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

I am trying to add new row by clicking add new button. Row contains below

```
<div class="col-sm-12" id="totalRow" cnt="1">
    <div class="col-sm-6" style="margin-top: 10px; float: left; padding-left: 0;">
        <label for="reg_input">Masrafın Türü</label>
        <select id="s2_basic_masrafbutce" name="masrafTuruId">
             <option value=""></option>
             <optgroup label="Masraf Türleri">
                @Html.Action("_MasrafTurleriniGetir", "Ortak", new { ID = 0 })
             </optgroup>
         </select>
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-3" style="margin-top: 10px; float: right; padding-right: 0px;">
        <label for="reg_input">Masrafın Tutarı</label>
        <input type="text" id="@Html.IdFor(x => x.tutar)" class="form-control" name="tutar">
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-3" style="padding-right: 0; margin-top: 10px; float: right">
        <label for="reg_input">Fiş No</label>
        <input type="text" id="@Html.IdFor(x => x.fis_no)" class="form-control" name="fis_no">
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-6" style="margin-top: 20px; float: left; padding-left: 0">
        <label for="reg_input">Açıklama</label>
        <textarea name="MasrafAciklama" class="form-control" style="resize: none;">                      </textarea>
    </div>
</div>
```

How can I append

```
@Html.Action("_MasrafTurleriniGetir", "Ortak", new { ID = 0 })
```

into div by using javascript ?

I tried

```
$("#myDiv").append('<%=Html.Action("_MasrafTurleriniGetir", "Ortak", new { ID = 0 })');
```

but it's not working.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are apparently using the Razor view engine, so this should work

```
$("#myDiv").append('@Html.Action("_MasrafTurleriniGetir", "Ortak", new { ID = 0 })');
```

Also make sure the javascript is part of a `cshtml` file, not an external JavaScript file.

Comment: Yes it is working but I use foreach loop in _MasrafTurleriGetir and when I run this append code, I get  "unterminated string literal" error which strings are coming from _MasrafTurleriGetir.

Comment: I added <text>\</text> and "unterminated string literal" problem solved. Thank you btw.